# How does SAML work in relation to an application that is not a service provider?

Tags: saml

So I'm struggling a bit with the basics of the flow of SAML.  Here's the scenario I find confusing.

I have a java web application.  The user is logged in.  I know they want to order cookies from a 3rd party because they've clicked on the "I want chocolate chip cookies" link.  I also know that "Mrs. Pillsbury Cookies Co." is a "Service Provider" because she sent me her meta-data and I've registered her with my Gluu Server (IdP).  I've also sent her my IdP meta-data so we've done the whole hand-shaking thing.

My question is...how do I now send the SAMLResponse to Mrs. Pillsbury?  She's given me a SOAP endpoint that is waiting for a SAMLResponse.  How do I tell my Java application to get some XML from my gluu server as a SAMLReponse that I can then pass to the Pillsbury SOAP endpoint?  That's the part where I'm stuck...I don't know how to get a response to forward.  I can see in the metadata that there are lots of SSO endpoints

```
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" Location="https://idp.myjavaapp.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Unsolicited/SSO"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://idp.myjavaapp.com/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" Location="https://idp.myjavaapp.com/idp/profile/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO
```

Am I supposed to hit one of those SSO endpoints and it'll generate a response that I can then forward on to Pillsbury?  Can one of you SAML experts out there get me straigtened out?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting to send the user to Mrs. Pillsbury so they can interact directly? Or are you expecting the user to stay on your site and interact with Mrs. Pillsbury THROUGH you?

Comment: Expecting to send the user to Mrs Pillsbury's website.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways SAML Requests/Responses can be generated.

IdP initiated:

This is a SAML Response generated w/o a SAML request. This requires the user to login/be logged into the idP and the idP will generate a SAML Response based off the SP setup in the idp.

SP initiated:

This is usually an HTTP Redirect but can be a POST as well. This is a SAML Request Redirect/POST that gets sent to the idP based of some link or button on the SP's website.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you have the following relationship:

```
Your App
        \
         3rd Party ordering
        /
IdP Server
```

Your app needs to make a request to the 3rd party, but also need it to authenticate against the IdP. Yes?

Normally the process works such that the 3rd party requests the token itself. Your app shouldn't have the token intended for the 3rd party -- it should only have the token for its own app.

Usually you send whatever your app-specific request is to the 3rd party first. When they receive that bit of information they hold onto it and then make a SP-Initiated authentication request to your IdP. They will attach a bit of information as part of the auth request called relay state. This bit of information is used to reconstitute the session after the IdP responds.

Once the IdP receives the request it does whatever it needs to do to authenticate the user, and sends the token back to the 3rd party. As part of that response they also send the relay state. The 3rd party then verifies the token and sets the session as necessary, then reads the relay state and sets whatever internal state is necessary to continue the order.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. As the previous answers have explained, it can be done one of two ways: the SP site (Pillsbury) sends you an authentication request, or you can direct your IDP/Gluu server to send an SAML message to the SP without them prompting: "unsolicited".

In the case of the first "SP-Initiated", you just create a link to the SP site for the user's browser to follow. The user's browser hits the SP site, the SP site realizes that it needs to authenticate the user: so it creates a SAML Authentication Request to your IDP endpoint, directing the user's browser there.  Then your IDP server will respond according to the metadata/relationship that you've set up with the SP site. Just as one of the other answers explained, this Authentication Request can include a RelayState parameter which will be sent back to the SP to tell them where to send the user after the SAML message had been consumed & validated.  I haven't used Gluu but I believe the SP would use the second endpoint you showed in your question to do this.

In the case of the second "IDP-initiated", you need to direct the user's browser to one of the Gluu server endpoints to generate a SAML assertion, which will be POST'd back to the SP site without the SP site's prompting. This one is less used because every time the user is directed to the SP site from your site, they will be forced through the AuthN process among other reasons.  I believe this is the first listed endpoint that you showed in your question.

Here's a really good explanation of IDP-initiated from Shibboleth, that should help clear this up for you: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPUnsolicitedSSO

Best of luck!